# ul li List Style Navigation with some items right aligned

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a case where I have a ul li menu that I would like some of the elements to be aligned to the right.

I can't put a defined size because the menu changes and sometimes there are more or less nav elements.  Also sometimes there may be more then one item I want aligned right.

[image]

Here is a jsfiddle I started to demonstrate what I am trying to do in code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bjPAt/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="right_nav">Right Nav</a></li>
</ul>
```

** This may not be possible and I will have to change the html around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `float:right` the `<li>` tag not the `<a>` tag. See modified version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bjPAt/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

http://jsfiddle.net/bjPAt/5/